# Issue migrating to the new developement org

Tags: ant, deployment

I developed my application on a salesforce developer org and connected to it with the force.com IDE. I configured Jenkins to do the build and configured ANT migration to do the auto deployment. When I am trying to deploy from my developer org to other developer org using ANT migration tool I face the following issue:

> does not resolve to a valid sObject type 
>       field RecordType does not exist
>       no CustomField found
>       Invalid Field: Account.RecordType.DeveloperName
>       Error: In field: field - no CustomField named

and even more....

Package.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexClass</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexPage</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApexTrigger</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageComponent</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>HomePageLayout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Layout</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>StaticResource</name>
    </types>
    <version>33.0</version>
</Package>
```

is there any workaround?

Comment: In which metadata file is the reference to Account.RecordType.DeveloperName?

Can you show us the full stacktrace?

Comment: are you sure everythign is included in your package.xml and that you've already configured all settings that aren't supported by the metadata api which you may have dependancies on ?

Comment: Is there anyway that I can add all customfields and recordtypes?

Answer (score 1):

You need update your package.xml and include all required metadata, such as RecordType, Custom Fields, etc.

Comment: I have added package.xml file in my original question